# How to add wrap div to via get data variable and append to default content?

Tags: jquery

I need help to add wrap div to default content from getting data variable.

Default content:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="read" value="ADD CONTENT" />
```

When clicked to button:

```
$.get("read.php", function(data) {
$(".list").append(data).wrap('<div class="item"><div class="icon"></div></div>'");
});
});
```

read.php data:

```
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL</div></div></div>
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL-1</div><div class="col">COL-2</div></div></div>
```

How can I do like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div class="icon"></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL</div></div></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="icon"></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL-1</div><div class="col">COL-2</div></div></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jsfiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/vj0u3p84/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jwr156vx/1/)**.

You could use `filter()` to loop through the containers then wrap them like :

```js
$("#read").click(function() {

  var data = `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL</div></div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col">COL-1</div><div class="col">COL-2</div></div></div>`;

  $(data).filter('.container').each(function() {
    $(".list").append($('<div class="item"><div class="icon"></div></div>').append($(this)));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="read" value="ADD CONTENT" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer and info about `filter()`